# Intelij idea exported Java Jar file doesnt work properly java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, keystore, executable-jar, truststore

**Hello Everyone!!
I am developing a server app in java lang in intelij idea it works properly
but when exporting as .jar file it gives an error like this**

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:177)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:190)
        at com.company.ProxyServer.listen(ProxyServer.java:24)
        at com.company.ProxyServer.run(ProxyServer.java:18)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1917)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:110)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:74)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:942)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1111)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf(Provider.java:1928)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:1935)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1910)
        ... 8 more
```

**My main class which is  Main.java like below it doesn't work and i don't know why?**

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "files/keystore.jks");
            //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "files/server.cer");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "12345");

       new Thread(new ProxyServer(Utils.SERVER_PORT_TO_LISTEN)).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Keystore points to a file which is not accessible when the file is inside the jar.

Comment: I solved this problem as put keystore.jks to outside of jar file and call it inside of jar file.